# Use a \ref{} value to set a counter value

Tags: cross-referencing

How does one set the value of a counter to the value obtained from a `\ref{}` command?

I am using the `xr` package to access labels from another document; I want to add the value of a `\ref{}` to a counter in my current document.

I tried `\setcounter{newcount}{\value{\ref{oldlabel}}}` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

This is a job for the `\setcounterref` command from the [`refcount`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/refcount) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newcounter{newcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\caption{test}\label{ref:A}\end{figure}
\setcounterref{newcount}{ref:A}
The value of \texttt{newcount} is \thenewcount

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's perfect. I had forgotten about that package. Thanks.