# Using reference labels in mathematical calculations

Tags: cross-referencing, calculations

**EDIT**: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120203/14103) points to a good solution.

---

I wanted to use reference labels in mathematical calculations and was under the impression that if I use the `calc` package, it will be rather straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}

\linenumbers
First line

Second line\label{ls}

As found in \arabic{\ref{ls}-1}

\end{document}
```

As we find, this does not work.

*(My actual calculations will more complex than this. This is a toned down version.)*

Comment: `\arabic{}` needs the name of a counter. It is defined as `\def\arabic#1{\expandafter\@arabic\csname c@#1\endcsname}`.

Comment: @cfr Then,  how do I engage a label in calculation?

Comment: Tried `\setcounter{x}{\ref{ls}-1}` which did not work.

Comment: Pick your poison? But I'm far from good at this stuff. But I would think: (1) go lower level TeX; (2) use something like `pgfmath` or the TikZ `math` library; (3) use something like the `fp` package; (4) use `expl3` (maybe).

Comment: Or, in this case, just counters. But `\ref{ls}` doesn't return anything for me anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) and [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lineno,refcount}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\linenumbers
First line

Second line\linelabel{ls}

As found in \calc{\getrefnumber{ls}-1}

\end{document}
```

`\getrefnumber` expands its argument (defaulting to `0` if the references haven't settled), making it useful in calculations.

While the above example uses [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno) (and therefore a package-specific `\linelabel` for labelling some reference, the above usage should work with the standard `\label`-`\ref` system as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in a simple case. Obviously, I don't know what your more complex usage requires. This just uses LaTeX counters.

I've changed the reference to use an enumeration because `\ref{ls}` did not return a number, so obviously could not be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First line
    \item Second line\label{ls}
  \end{enumerate}
  \newcounter{mycounter}
  \setcounter{mycounter}{\ref{ls}}
  \addtocounter{mycounter}{-1}
  As found in \arabic{mycounter}
\end{document}
```

[image: calculated outcome]

Comment: Use of `refcount` package as per this answer, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120203/14103 provided a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution:

**Edit:** The first version of this code contained a stupid error that prevented it from working when the number generated by the reference contained more than one digit; I have now corrected this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\@ifdefinable\striphbox{\def\striphbox#1\hbox#2% #1 is the number, #2 is {}
  {{#1}}
}
\newcommand*\calcref[2]{%
  \ifcsname r@#1\endcsname
    \begingroup
      \edef\cs{\ref{#1}}%
      \def\next##1{\numexpr #2\relax}%
      \number\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\next\expandafter\striphbox\cs
    \endgroup
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First line
    \setcounter{enumi}{10}
    \item Second line\label{ls}
  \end{enumerate}
  As found in~\calcref{ls}{#1-1} and in~\calcref{ls}{7*#1+5}\ldots
\end{document}
```

In the first argument of `\calcref` you pass the symbolic label, in the second one you pass a numeric expression in which `#1` marks the spot where the number from the reference should be included.